# Validate country specific characters

Tags: java

In my application, I'd like to ensure user input consistss of characters valid for his/her localization e.g. Polish based user is allowed to use letter 'ó' but not German 'ü'.

What is a good practice to implement this validator ?

Comment: The good practice is not to implement such a pointless restriction.

Comment: Why do you think it is pointless ? And for learning sake, is it regex the only way to handle this type of validation ?

Comment: I don’t know what purpose your hypothetical input has. Why should a Polish user not be able to enter the name of their German colleague or the name of a German city or a German product sold in Poland under the original name? Or, to ask the other way round: what actual harm do you want to prevent by not allowing a Polish user to enter `ü`?

Comment: e.g. using some kind of print service which only supports characters present in native language. I know it's very unlikely scenario. I'm good with the answer that we do not do that. But whenever I'd like to write user input validation should I use regex ?

Comment: Whether a print service handles certain characters depends on the charset encoding and/or fonts in use, but not on the user’s language configured while entering the data. Each user can have a different language setting but that obviously doesn’t affect the system’s global printing service. Still, even a printing service can change after the user entered data. Besides that, there is no rule what to use for input validation. If you want to use regex, use it, if you want to use something else, use something else.